# How to query Core Data for a date between two others dates in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an (`NSManagedObject`) class called `TodoItem` that has two date attributes (`startDate` and `endDate`) and I wanna query Core Data for objects of this class. Here is the code:

```
import CoreData

class TodoItem: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var name: String!
    @NSManaged var addedDate: NSDate!
    @NSManaged var doneDate: NSDate!
}
```

In my controller, I wanna create another date object for the current time `var currentDate = NSDate()` and query all `TodoItem` objects where `currentDate` is between their `addedDate` and `doneDate`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the predicate:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"%@ >= addedDate AND %@ <= doneDate", currentDate, currentDate)
```

If you need more help with how to create and use CoreData queries, I would suggest checking out one of the numerous tutorials available on the web.